# Copy to client clipboard after mouse selection with tmux in a remote session

Tags: ssh, copy-paste, tmux, iterm

This is my .tmux.conf

```
setw -g mouse on
set-option -s set-clipboard off
bind-key -T copy-mode MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -selection clipboard -i"
```

Works well on a linux machine locally. Mouse selection is copied to system clipboard automatically.

However, in a remote session (iTerm + Mac), it doesn't work. Text isn't copied to the client's system clipboard. Apparently I have to use OSC 52. Here is a [helper script](https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/HEAD/hterm/etc/osc52.sh).

You can use the script like so:

`echo "whatever text" | osc52.sh`

Now "whatever text" is copied to the client's system clipboard.

However I can't get the script to work with tmux mouse selection:

```
setw -g mouse on
set-option -s set-clipboard off
osc52="~/osc52.sh"
bind-key -T copy-mode MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "$osc52"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am also facing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to use OSC 52. You can't send it from a script - all output from commands run from copy-pipe is ignored.

Instead, you need to configure tmux itself to do it. Try the following:

1) Remove the bind-key command and just leave MouseDragEnd1Pane as the default which is copy-selection.

2) Change set-clipboard off to set-clipboard on. Remember to restart tmux entirely after changing .tmux.conf.

3) Make sure TERM outside tmux is xterm or xterm-256color so that tmux adds the Ms capability from the default terminal-overrides. This should be the default in iTerm2. Make sure you are not removing it from terminal-overrides in .tmux.conf.

4) In iTerm2, I think you need to turn on this option, "Applications in terminal may access clipboard":

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. This is my .tmux.conf: setw -g mouse on set-option -s set-clipboard on

Comment: Did you restart tmux entirety after changing .tmux.conf? What does `echo $TERM` say outside tmux? What does `tmux show -s terminal-overrides` say inside tmux?

Comment: xterm-256color and terminal-overrides[0] "xterm*:XT:Ms=\\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\\007:Cs=\\E]12;%p1%s\\007:Cr=\\E]112\\007:Ss=\\E[%p1%d q:Se=\\E[2 q"
terminal-overrides[1] "screen*:XT

Comment: This should work, maybe you need to change something else in iTerm2.